# Running Jasper Reports against an in-memory h2 datasource?

Tags: postgresql, grails, jasper-reports, grails-orm, h2

I'm trying to run jasper reports against a live and reporting database, but any reports run against the live database throw exceptions about not finding the right tables (although the default PUBLIC schema is found). It looks like the main `DataSource` connection isn't honoring the H2 connection settings which specify `IGNORECASE=true`, as the generated columns and tables are capitalized, by my queries are not.

**DataSource.groovy** dataSource:

```
dataSource {
    hibernate {
        cache.use_second_level_cache = false
        cache.use_query_cache = false
    }

    dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MODE=PostgreSQL;IGNORECASE=TRUE;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false"
    jndiName = null
    dialect = null 
}
```

**Datasources.groovy** dataSource:

```
datasource(name: 'reporting') {
    environments(['development', 'test'])
    domainClasses([SomeClass])
    readOnly(false)
    driverClassName('org.h2.Driver')
    url('jdbc:h2:mem:testReportingDb;MODE=PostgreSQL;IGNORECASE=TRUE;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false')
    username('sa')
    password('')
    dbCreate('create-drop')
    logSql(false)
    dialect(null)
    pooled(true)
    hibernate {
        cache {
            use_second_level_cache(false)
            use_query_cache(false)
        }
    }
}
```

What fails:

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiledReport, params,dataSource.getConnection())
```

While debugging, the only difference I've found is that the live dataSource, when injected or looked up with `DatasourcesUtils.getDataSource(null)`, is a `TransactionAwareDatasourceProxy`, and `DatasourcesUtils.getDataSource('reporting')` is a `BasicDataSource`

What do I need to do for Jasper to operate on the active in-memory H2 database?

This failure is not reproducible against a real postgres database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't run reports against in-memory datasources, and this won't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are opening a different database. Using the database URL `jdbc:h2:mem:testDb` will open an [in-memory database within the same *process* and *class loader*](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases).

Did you try already using a regular persistent database, using the database URL `jdbc:h2:~/testDb`?

To use open an in-memory database that is running in a different process or class loader, you need to use the [server mode](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes). That means, you need to [start a server](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server) where the database is running, and connect to it using `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:testDb`.

See also the [database URL overview](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url).

Comment: `autoServer=TRUE` still fails, and manually starting databsases is not an option. `jdbc:h2:~/testDb` fails, as does using a file reference explicitly, with all combinations of lock modes and close delays. The second in-memory database *works*, and the connection can be used both by the running grails application *and* jasper reports.

Comment: What version of H2 do you use? With 'fails' you mean the tables are not available? If you get an exception, could you post it?

Comment: I updated my question. The issue seems to be that the tables and columns get capitalized within H2, which should be fine given `IGNORECASE=true`, but when I pass the connection, queries with lowercase table/column names fail, only with the one datasource.

I'm using H2 1.3.159.

Comment: So that obviously wasn't the right answer. I wrote another answer now.

Answer (score 1):

H2 doesn't currently support case-insensitive identifiers (table names, column names). I know other databases support it, but currently H2 uses regular `java.util.HashMap<String, ..>` for metadata, and that's case sensitive (whether or not `IGNORECASE` is used).

In this case, the identifier names are case-sensitive. I tried with the database URL `jdbc:h2:mem:testReportingDb;MODE=PostgreSQL;IGNORECASE=TRUE;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false` using the H2 Console:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS UPPER;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lower;
CREATE TABLE UPPER(NAME VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE lower(name VARCHAR(255));

-- ok:
SELECT * FROM UPPER;
SELECT * FROM lower;

-- fail (table not found):
SELECT * FROM upper;
SELECT * FROM LOWER;
```

So, the question is: when creating the tables, were they created with uppercase identifiers or a different database URL? Is it possible to change that? If not: is it possible to use a different database URL?

Comment: The problem is that the tables are created automatically by GORM in both cases, so I don't see why the caps would randomly vary.

Comment: You can verify what statements are executed by adding ;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=2 to the database URL - and then check the .trace.db file.

Comment: +1 for trace. I'll try that out tomorrow if I get time. My workaround for now is to not run reporting with in-memory databases, as controlled with some smart wiring